# how to show output console in GUI using Java Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, netbeans

Im using netbeans with design (palette).
I want to show my output console into GUI in netbeans.
So here is my code that I want to execute.
I put this to button function, and it works.
But I the result show up in output console, I intention to show it in the interface too.

```
User user = status.getUser();
            Date dated = status.getCreatedAt();
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            Connection conne = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                conne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");
                System.out.println(status);
                System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set names 'utf8'");
                stmt.execute();
                stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set character set utf8");
                stmt.execute();
                stmt = conne.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tweet(ID,date,name,statusLocation,text,source) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                stmt.setInt(1, (int) status.getId());
                stmt.setString(2, getTimeStamp());
                stmt.setString(3, status.getUser().getScreenName());
                stmt.setString(4, user.getLocation());
                stmt.setString(5, status.getText());
                stmt.setString(6, status.getSource());
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("this record inserted!");
                System.out.println("==================");
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning sw) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }
    };       
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
    double lat1 = 121.300000d;
    double long1 = 25.020000d;
    double lat2 = 121.380000d;
    double long2 = 25.030000d;
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    double[][] bb = {{lat1, long1}, {lat2, long2}};
    fq.locations(bb);
    twitterStream.filter(fq);}
```

When the 'run' button executed, the result just displayed in the output console, not in my interface.

And this is my interface look like:
[image]

Thank you so much for any reply

Comment: It shows in the console because you send it to the console: System.out.println(), if you want to display it in your graphical element, you need to call the element's method which will display your text

Comment: sorry it seems different. I dont know. thank you, Barbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the calls to `System.out.println` with  `jTextArea1.append` where jTextArea1 is the name of whatever that TextArea is in your interface. You may also want to add a `\n` to end of each string.

Comment: how if I want to replace this: System.out.println(status);

Comment: it still error. it said cannot find symbol, appendText(String)

Comment: oh I know!. I just add blank string and it works: jTextArea1.appendText(" "+status+"\n"); Thank you so much WillShackleford! My burden was gone :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use jTextarea or jtextfield or in my case i used jlabels to display my output to the console ..

For example : If i have my result in my result variable use this result variable to set your output like

`this.jLabel1.setText(Result);` //This show out in the GUI where you put your label

similarly same case with other elements

`this.jTextField1.setText(Result);`

Comment: what is 'this' refer to?